# how to query for search using 'like' code in mysql with %s

Tags: php, mysql

i have sql query to search some keyword like this

```
if (isset($_POST['no_peserta_mhs_2015'])) {
$colname_rec_mhs_2015 = $_POST['no_peserta_mhs_2015'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_rec_mhs_2015 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = %s or nama_mhs_2015 like %s ", GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"), GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"));
```

I  have problem if when i search name with `nama_mhs_2015 like %s`, i must enter complete name, i just want if i enter one part of name, my query can find the whole name in my table database.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

From:

```
$query_rec_mhs_2015 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = %s or nama_mhs_2015 like %s ", GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"), GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"));
```

To: `//I've chage %s to '/%'`

```
$query_rec_mhs_2015 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = '%s' OR nama_mhs_2015 like '%s' ", GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"), GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query_rec_mhs_2015 = sprintf("
    SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE nama_mhs_2015 like %s 
    ", 
 GetSQLValueString('%' . str_replace(array('%', '_') , array('\%' ,'\_'), $colname_rec_mhs_2015) . '%', "text")
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your respon, but i try your solution and get syntax error

Comment: my error syntax  gone, but if i enter value like 'fran' i get error mysql syntax like this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fran'' OR nama_mhs_2015 like ''fran''' at line 2`

Comment: ok. then magic is in your GetSQLValueString. try updated variant

Answer (score 0):

why not use :

```
if (isset($_POST['no_peserta_mhs_2015'])) {
$colname_rec_mhs_2015 = $_POST['no_peserta_mhs_2015'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_rec_mhs_2015 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = %s or nama_mhs_2015 like '%%%s%%' ", GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"), GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"));
```

hope it help :)

Comment: always echo the string in sprintf (or var_dump), and you'll find the right sql query for you ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code has to be changed to

`%s` to `'%s'` but in first case where you are using **=** will not be able to use **%** whereas the wild characters work with LIKE operator.

so your query will be

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = 's' or nama_mhs_2015 like '%s%'", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"),
GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"));
```

for better understand-ability for [wildcard characters](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) to be used in SQL

Comment: thanks, but i get  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fran'' at line 1`

Comment: Can you Print the Full Query. what you are getting? What is the input you are giving is it fran' or fran

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer, i have been solve my problem with simple syntax like this:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM mhs_2015 WHERE no_peserta_mhs_2015 = %s or nama_mhs_2015 LIKE %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rec_mhs_2015, "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rec_mhs_2015 . "%", "text"));
```